# Integral involving inverse of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, contest-math, inverse

My brother gave me the following problem:

Let $f:[1;\infty)\to[1;\infty)$ be such that for $x≥1$ we have $f(x)=y$ where $y$ is the unique solution of $y^y=x$. Then calculate:
$$
\int_0^e f(e^x)dx
$$
I couldn't figure out something helpful, so any help is highly appreciated. I think he has the problem from some contest, but  I don't know, from which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $x=u\ln u$.  Note that $1\ln 1 = 0$ and $e\ln e = e$.  Thus
$$
\int_0^e f(e^x) \,dx
= \int_1^e f(e^{u\ln u}) (1+\ln u)\,du
= \int_1^e u(1+\ln u)\,du \\
= \int_1^e (u + u\ln u)\,du
= \left[\tfrac14 u^2 + \tfrac12 u^2\ln u\right]_1^e
= \tfrac34 e^2 - \tfrac14
$$

Comment: I was writing mine and got taken away from my computer so I didn't see yours before I posted mine. Yours is essentially identical (+1), so I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we have to solve $y^y=x$ for $y$. Using techniques from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples), we get

$$f(x)=y=\frac{\ln x}{W(\ln x)},$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Now if $x>0$, then

$$f(e^x)=\frac{x}{W(x)}.$$

Form here we have to [know](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%2FProductLog%5Bx%5D%2Cx%5D), that

$$\int \frac{x}{W(x)} \, dx = \frac{x^2(2W(x)+1)}{4W^2(x)} + C.$$

This integral comes from a [tricky](http://www.had2know.com/academics/lambert-w-function-calculator.html) substitution.

Between $0$ and $e$ integral limits it has the value

$$\int_0^e f(e^x) \, dx = \int_0^e \frac{x}{W(x)} \, dx = -\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}e^2.$$

Comment: Thank you, pretty straightforward. But are there more elementary ways to evaluate the integral? For example, I thought of the substitution $x=z\cdot\ln(z)$ because then, we would have $f(e^{z\cdot\ln(z)})=f(z^z)=z$ so it would simplify the integral. I couldn't find out the integral limits after the substitution tough.

Comment: @user109899 In this way you will need to use Lambert W function to evaluate the integral limits.